# Why showing "Show [count] more comments" when there are no comments?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

Checkout comments section on this question, [How is assignment made in this expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172777/how-is-assignment-made-in-this-expression). I've flagged few comments and they got removed, but still we can see like this,

add a comment | show **6** more comments

but when you click on "show **6** more comments" link, that link will go hide and only "add a comment" link will be display.

Is it a bug?

**Update**: Before I posting my question, one user commented on it, and the above thing get resolved.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44249/the-system-sees-a-comment-that-doesnt-exist

Comment: It's also possible there was actually a 6-comment set beforehand that got spontaneously nuked or moved to chat. I've never seen 6 disappear before.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue.  The comments were deleted but the cached comment count wasn't invalidated.  An action that required the cache to be updated resulted in it being fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment counter increments as comments are added but does not get decremented when they are deleted until you refresh the post.  If it's really out of sync we run a batch process that fixes up the count.